# Convert htaccess for nginx

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

Quick question for the htaccess gurus out there.

How can I convert this .htaccess file for nginx?

```
<IfModule   mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine   On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$  index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule in your `location /` directive with your other rule.

```
location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 last;
}
```

Then reload or restart server.

Comment: No that doesn't seem to be working, even the root route is failing with this rewrite on

Comment: Can you show me the full directive where you are applying the rule.